# remove lines from text file that contain specific text

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to remove lines that contain 0/0 or ./. in column 71 "FORMAT.1.GT" from a tab delimited text file.
I've tried the following code but it doesn't work. What is the correct way of accomplishing this? Thank you

```
my $cmd6 = `fgrep -v "0/0" | fgrep -v "./." $Variantlinestsvfile > $MDLtsvfile`; print "$cmd6";
```

Comment: Do you want to remove entire line?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the entire line. Thank

Comment: cat old_file.txt | sed '/\.\/\./d' | sed '/0\/0/d' > new_file.txt

Comment: may it help you! It's not the most beautiful way!

Comment: @FrancisconSantos - OP wants it from column 71. it will delete lines wherever it finds in whole line. This is not the correct approach.

Comment: I would prefer to be specific to col 71, if possible. Thanks

Comment: Do I understand the requirement correctly:  if either `0/0` or `./.` are found starting at column 71, drop the line. (In this case the _"FORMAT..._ is not of essence, correct?)

Comment: I'm still unclear what _column 71_ means: Is it the 71st tab-separated field (like borodin assumes) or the 71st character in the line (like zdim assumes)?

Comment: It's a tab delimited file. Column 71 sometimes contains 0/0 or ./. I would like to remove these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call a one-liner as borodin and zdim said. Which one is right for you is still not clear because you don't tell whether *71st column* means the 71st tab-separated field of a line or the 71st character of that line. Consider

```
12345\t6789
```

Now what is the 2nd column? Is it the character `2` or the field `6789`? Borodin's answer assumes it's `6789` while zdim assumes it's `2`. Both showed a solution for either case but these solutions are stand-alone solutions. Programs of its own to be run from the commandline.

If you want to integrate that into your Perl script you could do it like this:

Replace this line:

```
my $cmd6 = `fgrep -v "0/0" | fgrep -v "./." $Variantlinestsvfile > $MDLtsvfile`; print "$cmd6";
```

with this snippet:

```
open( my $fh_in, '<', $Variantlinestsvfile ) or die "cannot open $Variantlinestsvfile: $!\n";
open( my $fh_out, '>', $MDLtsvfile ) or die "cannot open $MDLtsvfile: $!\n";
while( my $line = <$fh_in> ) {

    # character-based:
    print $fh_out $line unless (substr($line, 70, 3) =~ m{(?:0/0|\./\.)});

    # tab/field-based:
    my @fields = split(/\s+/, $line);
    print $fh_out $line unless ($fields[70] =~ m|([0.])/\1|);
}
close($fh_in);
close($fh_out);
```

Use ***either*** the character-based line ***or*** the tab/field-based lines. Not both!

Borodin and zdim condensed this snippet to a one-liner, but you must not call that from a Perl script.

Comment: I'm ashamed because I only did a mash-up of two very good answers.

Comment: @PerlDog This is a very good post and a perfectly fine answer in my opinion -- you pulled together what is needed and in fact answered the question in a suitable way. All good I say :) I find it interesting that we never were told which way it is. So even after all is said and done, and past and gone, we still don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the exact position and know string lenghts [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) can find it

```
perl -ne 'print if not substr($_, 70, 3) =~ m{(?:0/0|\./\.)}' filename
```

This prints lines only when a three-character long string starting at 71st column does not match either of `0/0` and `./.`

The `{}` delimiters around the regex allow us to use `/` and `|` inside without escaping.  The `?:` is there so that the `()` are used only for grouping, and not capturing. It will work fine also without `?:` which is there only for efficiency's sake.

Comment: True, if _column 71_ means: 71st character in the line.

Comment: @zdim. my $cmd6 = `perl -ne 'print if not substr($_, 70, 3) =~ m{(?:0/0|\./\.)}' $currenttsvfile > $MDLtsvfile`; print "$cmd6";  gave me errors when I ran it from my Perl script.

Comment: @user3781528  Sorry that I didn't respond to your message -- I just didn't see it until now. (I think it's because there is a period after username?)  You did get an explanation and your good answer so all is well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ane 'print unless $F[70] =~ m|([0.])/\1|' myfile > newfile
```

Comment: True, if _column 71_ means: 71st tab-separated field.

Comment: @PerlDog: We're told it's a tab-separated file, and column number rarely means character position. Besides, character position is very vague if there are tabs involved, especially when we don't know the size of the tab stops

Comment: Given that, your answer is right. But zdim's answer was also upvoted so someone must have thought it's the 71st character.

Comment: I get "Global symbol "@F" requires explicit package name" error

Comment: @user3781528: That's a self-contained Perl program. You should enter it on the command line, not as part of a script file

Comment: @user3781528 That's because you are calling borodin's and zdim's Perl one-liners from within your Perl program. Don't do that. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
awk '{ if ($71 != "./." && $71 != ".0.") print ;  }' old_file.txt  > new_file.txt
```

Comment: There are people out here who would blame you for the _[useless use of cat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/5830574)_. I don't, but be prepared.

Comment: @PerlDog Count me in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your command is that you are attempting to capture the output of a command which produces no output - all the matches are redirected to a file, so that's where all the output is going.

Anyway, calling `grep` from Perl is just wacky. Reading the file in Perl itself is the way to go.

If you do want a single shell command,

```
grep -Ev $'^([^\t]*\t){70}(\./\.|0/0)\t' file
```

would do what you are asking more precisely and elegantly. But you can use that regex straight off in your Perl program just as well.